# Failed with 0x80004005 to create the view query or web parts for web

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, feature-activation

Feature 1 creates Site Columns

Feature 2 creates Content Type and adds the site columns created by feature1

Feature 3 creates a List definition for mylist

I have two Web tempaltes. I have added following List view to both onet.xml

```
<View List="Lists/mylist" BaseViewID="0" WebPartZoneID="Left" WebPartOrder="2"  />
```

for one of them it works but for another one it generates

```
Failed with 0x80004005 to create the view query or web parts for web
```

I thought maybe features activates randomly and feature 3 actives before 2 and 1. I activated them programmatically one by one but still when I crate new site by powershell one of webtemplates works not another one.

Comment: Solvd: the URL attribute of Element.xml file of the list definition must mutch the List attribute of view element in onet.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Medes,

If its just about feature-activation, you can define feature activation dependency on the later features... Feature Activation dependency means the feature is dependant on other features for its activation, you can see here how you can do this:
http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2011/03/12/feature-activation-dependencies-in-visual-studio-2010/

And more details on Feature Activation dependency can be found here:
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=607

Comment: thanks, It is not feature-activation issue because I tested and activated feature one by one programmatically still not working.

Comment: I found the reason why it does not work. the url of the element.xml of list definition must be exact as list attribute for View element in onet.xml file

Comment: Great you solved the problem :)